# Struts plugin for A/B testing?

Tags: java, struts2, struts, ab-testing

I am trying to incorporate server-side A/B testing for a UI built in Java using Struts framework. Are there any good Struts plugins for the purpose?

Comment: None that I'm aware of, but depending on how you need it to behave, I'd think it'd be relatively easy to do with an interceptor.